# Is there a method of opening a .blend file specifically as a library for editting?

Tags: blend-files

I have a blend file that's accumulated a lot of junk like hundreds of unused materials and I just want to erase them all. Does blender have a feature similar to append where it opens a .blend file as a library like a file manager, except one where I can select all the materials and just delete them? I feel like it would be pretty useful to have so that you could copy/cut/move/delete all the things you can ordinarily only append.

Comment: Usually blender automatically deletes all unused materials (not assigned to objects) at the next start up, so if you close the file and reopen it, they will be gone, unless marked as a fake-user, the icon that marked with letter (F) next to the material name, in this case it won't be deleted.

Comment: @Georges I had selected all of my objects, removed the materials from my active object and used 'copy material to others' so I wouldn't have to go through hundreds of objects to delete the materials. The materials aren't being used but they don't have an F next to them.

Comment: after you save and restart Blender, do you still have the materials?

Comment: @Georges I did restart Blender a few times, but it didn't do anything. It's working fine now, so I think it might have just been a glitch.

Comment: The outliner can handle the files content very well. You are probably looking for the **Orphan Data** or **Blend File** in the Outliner.